# Methods, and Loops

Tags: java

My Issue is that this code does not return and values when I call it.

I need to to read a set of values from another txt file and print out the answers. 
Then I need to be able to have it print to another empty text file.

The values in the txt file is (without space in-between lines):

```
1 2 3 4 5 6
4 5 6
7.5 8.5 9
8.1 9.2 10.3
```

The source code as follows:

```
public class Lab5d {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        // Scan the input
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String line = scan.nextLine();
        Scanner lineScan = new Scanner(line);
        // Process each line separately
        // If the next token is a double, assume there is an input line
        while (scan.hasNextDouble()) {

            processLine(line);

        }
    }

    public static void processLine(String line) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner lineScan = new Scanner(line);
        double a = lineScan.nextDouble();

        double sum;
        double product;
        double count;
        double average;

        sum = 0;
        count = 0;
        product = 1;
        while (lineScan.hasNext()) {

            sum = sum + a;
            product = product * a;
            ++count;
        }
        double ave = sum / count;

        System.out.printf("sum= %.1f, product= %.1f, ave= %.1f, count= %.1f%n", sum, product, ave, count);
    }
}
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: I'd suggest it's time to do some debugging.  If you have a debugger and know how to use it, that makes life easier.  And there's always the option of the "poor-man's debugger": temporarily insert diagnostic output statements at key points to show you where the program is executing and what the values of important variables are.

Answer (score 0):

You're not reading the file in. Use the file path as a parameter for the `Scanner` object.

Comment: I have been using the command java Lab4d<numbers.txt  which is the command to input the txt file into the code is it not? Its running in cmd btw.

Answer (score 0):

It can be two cases, you can either read values from a file or values from a command line.

First a main method look:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    // Scan the input
    processSystemIn();
    // San the file
    processFile("resource/values.txt");
}
```

The values.txt is following the format you presented in your question.
And read a value line by line using a hasNextLine method of a Scanner class then, use an another scanner instance for the each number from the line input.

case 1: A processSystemIn method with System.in

```
private static void processSystemIn() {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String line = null;

    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        line = scanner.nextLine();
        processLine(line);
    }

    scanner.close();
}
```

case 2: A processFile method with file.

```
private static void processFile(String fileName) {
    try {
        File file = new File(fileName);
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
        String line = null;
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            line = scanner.nextLine();
            processLine(line);
        }
        scanner.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The processLine method is a little bit different with yours.
With a hasNextDouble method, you can get a value.

See the method as follows:

```
public static void processLine(String line) {
    Scanner lineScan = new Scanner(line);
    double a;;
    double sum;
    double product;
    double count;
    double average;
    sum = 0;
    count = 0;

    while(lineScan.hasNextDouble())
    {
        a = lineScan.nextDouble();

        product = 1;
        sum += a;
        product *= a;
        ++count;
        average = sum / count;

        System.out.printf("sum= %.1f, product= %.1f, ave= %.1f, count= %.1f%n", sum, product, average, count);
    }

    lineScan.close();
}
```

The result is here:
[image]

Does this result meet your expectation?

I hope this helps.